# What meaning is Depth and T-Depth in Quantum Circuit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I'm reading a paper about quantum cryptanalysis and circuits designs, but i really can't understanding what is Circuit Depth or T-Depth. Also T-gate and T-count.

the paper is "Applying Grover’s algorithm to AES: quantum resource estimates"

Answer (score 2):

Generally, a depth of circuit is number of gates in row. However, you have to distinguish between number of basic (or physical) gates and composed gates. For example, if you have one Toffoli gate, the depth can be one (composed gates) or 12 in basic gates $H$, $T$, $T ^\dagger$ and CNOT (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate#Related_logic_gates) how Toffoli gate can be constructed).

$T$-depth is a number of $T$ gates in row, or in general number of any non-Clifford gates in row. The reason for bothering about $T$-depth is the fact that non-Clifford gates cannot be simulated efficiently on classical computer and mainly because it takes much longer time to apply them in circuits on real quantum processor in comparison with Clifford gates.